Split screen stereoscopic 360 VR video in Android ExoPlayer
I want to make 360 stereoscopic(two eyes) video in ExoPlayer, but i only manage to get 360 video
What i want
My onCreate method.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vr)
        window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)

        val i = intent
        videoUrl = i.getStringExtra(VRActivity.EXTRA_URL)
            ?: "https://multiplatform-f.akamaihd.net/i/multi/will/bunny/big_buck_bunny_,640x360_400,640x360_700,640x360_1000,950x540_1500,.f4v.csmil/master.m3u8"

        vrPlayer = findViewById(R.id.vr_player)
        (vrPlayer.videoSurfaceView as SphericalGLSurfaceView)
                .setDefaultStereoMode(C.STEREO_MODE_LEFT_RIGHT)

        bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(this)
                .build()
    }

I made C.STEREO_MODE_LEFT_RIGHT like here, but nothing change.
So there is any way to do it with Exoplayer or other lib?
